# JavaScript の関数で使われている "=>" は何を表していますか？

Tags: javascript

javascriptで20歳以上の方を配列から取り除くプログラムを書いているのですが、構文が複雑でわからないです。

`unit =>` この不等号は何を意味しているんですか？おそらく不等号ではないと思う。普段Pythonを触るのでこの書き方がいまいち分かりません。

```
function reject(array, iteratorFunction) {
  const returnVal = array.filter(unit => {
    return iteratorFunction(unit) === false;
  });
  return returnVal;
}

let ages = [10, 20, 30, 40];
let teen = reject(ages, function(age){
  return age >= 20;
});
```

Comment: タイトルは感想ではなくて、主題を書くようにしましょう。『 Javascript構文における「=>」について』とかかな？そうすることでタイトルだけでJavascriptの構文に関する質問とひと目で分かりますし、本文を読む際にも明確になり、回答が集まりやすいでしょう。

Comment: タイトルは今回、私が編集してしまいましたが、ヘルプの [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) も参考にしてください。 / 多少長くなっても、内容が推測できるタイトルの方が中身を見てもらえる確率が上がります。

Comment: いつも回答の編集すいません。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

アロー関数です。

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

> アロー関数式は、より短く記述できる、通常の function 式の代替構文です。また、this, arguments, super, new.target を束縛しません。アロー関数式は、メソッドでない関数に最適で、コンストラクタとして使うことはできません。

今回のご質問の件では
`this`, `arguments`, `super`, `new.target`が出てきてないので、束縛に関することは考慮する必要はありません。つまり今回の場合は、単に無名関数を短く書くためだけに使われています。